# JAXB backward compatibility

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

Years ago I wrote an application that used JAXB to generate Java bindings for an XML schema. The application code and the schema have been updated quite a lot over the years, but the JAXB jars remained the same since 2008, which was when I started using JAXB for this application. I've been using Ant to build the application, including generating and compiling bindings, and everything worked fine on at least two XP Pro development machines. I made some changes to the schema and never had to think about JAXB.

Recently I tried to rebuild the application from scratch on a new laptop, and the build keeps failing. The new 64-bit laptop is running windows 7 Pro, it had a newer JDK (1.7.0_45) and a new version of Ant (1.9.3). I was able to get around some weird problems by switching to a yet newer version of ant (1.9.4) and switching to latest JAXB jars. At this point, I don't even remember what those issues were (but I can recreate them by reverting to older JAXB jars in SVN).

After upgrading JAXB, I ran into new problems. First of all, the xjc task in ant seems to be interpreting the `target` attribute differently; it threw some error and apparently the `destdir` has the semantic meaning that `target` used to have.

Second, this task no longer generates the `impl` package with the implementation classes whose names were supposed to end with Type, so the rest of my code fails with a bunch of compilation problems.

Is there a way to make the new JAXB version backward-compatible? My other options are try updating the code to work with the new bindings, which seems like a lot of unnecessary work, or reverting to old JDK and Ant.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late reply to the original post.  But should be good as a reference for other folks.  I met the same problem.  Here is what worked for me after going through much of the same struggles trying to rebuild JAXB 1.0 scheme/binding using later JDKs (8 and 7).

- My goal is to build with latest JDKs without the hassle of upgrading JAXB, if possible.
- JDK 7&8 failed building with JAXB 1.0 due to ClassCastException thrown from `<xjc>` possibly due to incompatible language features. JDK 5&6 work, however.
- I went through several attempts trying to upgrade to the latest JAXB 2.11.12,

  1. Update ant build file `<xjc>` task to replace *target* attribute with *deskdir*
  2. Change binding files syntax - *bindingStyle* attribute was removed in `<jxb:globalBindings>` in the latest JAXB - we use *modelGroupBinding*
  3. Adjust binding class files suffix to avoid name conflicts. Update sources for the new type names generated.
  4. There were still remaining name conflicts and source upgrades required.
- I decided to stop going further down the rabbit hole making all these changes and focus on finding just *one* version of JAXB that generates JDK 7&8 compatible sources but still support JAXB 1.0 schema and binding.
- Newer `<xjc>` task supports version specification by *source* attribute.  However, as the original poster found out, support of "1.0" was removed in later JAXB distributions
- The "Illgal version 1.0" error message when using `<xjc>` is due to support for version 1.0 was removed in since JAXB 2.2.7 (https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.11/docs/ch02.html#a-2-2-7)
- However, JAXB 2.2.6 doesn't work either.  There seems to be a bug in that "jaxb-xjc.jar" version not generating sources correctly based on the  attribute, resulting in the certain *ClassNotFoundException* during build.
- I read reports on JAXB 2.1.18 failing to respect "1.0" source as well
- Eventually I found JAXB 2.0.5 is to be *one* version that can generate JDK 7&8 compatible sources using JAXB 1.0 source schema and binding.

  - Drop in the JAXB-RI 2.0.5 libs and remove old jaxb-libs.jar
  - Add *source="1.0"* attribute the `<xjc>` task
  - No need to convert `<xjc>` *"target"* attribute to *"deskdir"* in this version
  - I have not tested more versions beyond 2.0.5 but it's possible there are higher versions that does the same

Answer (score 0):

Your old project seems to use JAXB 1 whereas all the tools now have JAXB 2.x by default.

Try the following in the XJC task:

- `source="1.0"`
- `target="1.0"`

See these documents:

- https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjcTask.html
- https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/jaxb-1_0.html

Comment: I think I tried something like this, but it didn't work, so I figured I was doing something wrong. I get the error _Illegal version 1.0_ when I specify these attributes with these values, or just `source="1.0"`. If I only specify `target="1.0"` I get _1.0 is not a valid version number Perhaps you meant @destdir?_. This is pretty confusing.